# Can a write to the datastore fail?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Say I'm creating an entity like this:

```
Answer answer = new Answer(this, question, optionId);
ofy().save().entity(answer);
```

Should I check whether the write process is successful?

Say I want to make another action (increment a counter), Should I make a transaction, that includes the writing process?

And also, how can I check if the writing process is successful?

Comment: Just have your write method return true on success, or return the new id.

Comment: [Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/#Java_Datastore_writes_and_data_visibility) is an important link from the official docs about the datastore writes.

Comment: @Stultuske it's a builtin method and you have no control over it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An error while saving will produce an exception. Keep in mind that since you are not calling `now()`, you have started an async operation and the actual exception may occur when the session is closed (eg, end of the request).

Yes, if you want to increment a counter, you need to start a transaction which encompasses the load, increment, and save. Also keep in mind that it's possible for a transaction to retry even though it is successful, so a naive transaction can possibly overcount. If you need a rigidly exact increment, the pattern is significantly more complex. All databases suffer from some variation of this problem.

Comment: How rare is an exception in the write process? Have you ever encountered one?

Comment: Sure, although it's quite rare these days (the HRD has been very reliable). Keep in mind that you can accidentally craft situations that will result in problems (like heavy contention on a single entity group).